# MVC2 Custom Editor Template outer validation box

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I've got a custom Editor Template that is essentially:

```
<div id="control">
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day, Model.Days)%>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month, Model.Months)%>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, Model.Years)%>
</div>
```

Whilst my validation is successful/fine with this control (ValidationMessageFor works) I have been unable to find how to highlight the control when validation fails (e.g. with a TextBoxFor the textbox border goes red if validation fails)

Does anyone know how I can add this behaviour with a custom editor template please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  If you can detect a validation error, then you should be able to apply the appropriate class.  Something like this, substitute in your own field name:

```
 <div id = "control" class="<%=ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("DateField") ? "" : "validation-error" %>">
```

Comment: Cheers, exactly the behaviour I was after (though I used ViewData.ModelState.IsValid to encompass the whole control rather than a single field)